# Can I create a DOM element without it being in the DOM using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of places that keep adding markup to my string that finally gets output by jQuery's `append` to a container. My question is - can I fake this markup being inside the DOM without it actually being there in order to perform operations such as `hasClass` on the item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you pass an HTML string to jQuery, that element (or elements) will be created inside the jQuery object, which can then be put into the DOM later:

```js
const $div = $('<div>someDiv</div>');
$div.addClass('foo');
console.log($div.hasClass('foo'));
$('body').append($div);
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please use `$('<div>', {text:"someDiv", "class":"foo", appendTo:"body"}); consol....etc` without the `appendTo` obviously since it's immediate.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan How so? Can you further explain why you should do it that way?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I would suggest that using the options object is really a matter of personal preference. If there is any performance difference it would be very insignificant

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Of course you can do that too, this is just an example to demonstrate that an element can exist separate from the DOM, before being appended